# How to configure connection pool for Riak

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, riak, cloud-foundry

I am trying to configure my riak connector similar to how I did my Datasource Service connector. (source below is from: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html)

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(5, 30, 3000);
    DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, null);
    return connectionFactory().dataSource("my-own-personal-sql", dbConfig);
}
```

How would I configure my pools size for riak in spring cloud?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that Spring Cloud Connectors has support for Riak out of the box (at least not at the time of me writing this). See [the list of supported connectors here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_supported_services).

You would need to follow the instructions here to [add support for a custom service](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html#_adding_service_support).

---

I would suggest taking a look at `java-cfenv` instead though. It's really intended to replace SCC and doesn't need to strictly support every service type that you want to connect to. It has generic ways of pulling the config that you need. It's also designed to integrate better with Spring Boot, if you're using that.

https://spring.io/blog/2019/02/15/introducing-java-cfenv-a-new-library-for-accessing-cloud-foundry-services

Hope that helps!

Comment: We built our own service connector for now, and its the way I am supposed to connect to Riak for now.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: I guess one additional question, does riak normaly have its own connection pool or does it do like a rest call and use the http connection pool?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that. You might want to fire off a new SO question.